# When calling a web method in Flex right before issuing a redirect, is there a chance there will not be enough time for the web method to execute?

Tags: web-services, actionscript-3, apache-flex, redirect, asynchronous

When calling a web method in Flex right before issuing a redirect, is there a chance there will not be enough time for the web method to execute?  As in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"
        creationComplete="ws.loadWSDL('some WSDL');">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function onLoad():void
            {
                ws.Log("some message");
                navigateToURL(new URLRequest("some URL"), "_self");
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:WebService id="ws" load="onLoad()">
        <mx:operation
            name="Log"
        />
    </mx:WebService>
</mx:Application>
```

A call to a logging web method is issued one line of code above a redirect on the same browser tab.  We don't care whether there's a fault event, and we're not looking for a return value here.  In this example, all that's relevant is whether that call to `ws.Log` finds itself all the way to the web service it's attempting to communicate with.

Is there any chance at all that the URL redirect will come into play before `ws.Log` has finished sending its message across the wire?  Neither documentation nor a SWF decompiler seemed to help very much in answering this question.  Thanks!

Comment: No the data was sent. Unless you cae for a response from the logging function.

Comment: And if you try to do it HttpService to the execution and go for the Get method and then call the WS if you answered the HttpService.

Comment: @The_asMan I believe you, but do you have a source I could show or a way I could explain it to someone else please?  I'm having to talk with somebody about a related issue.  Also do you want to change your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using workers your code will not be multi-threaded.
Because there are no workers you can assume that the code is run line-by-line
You didn't post what the "ws.Log" function does but I will assume it is the function making the call to the server and sending some kind of data.
Since there is no waiting for events you should not have a problem.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what it's supposed to do, but I'm using MXML and everything, so I just wanted to make sure there weren't asynchronous elements internal to just sending the message to the server.